# Forwarding parameters for late initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I'm trying to build a general tcp_server a template, and I want to forward some parameters to the client class after the connection is created. However, the client object creation happens only after he has connected, and not during the tcp_server construction. How do I pass the parameters from the tcp_server constructor to the client constructor ? The parameters shouldn't be copied, only referenced.

The code bellow is what I've modeled so far, but I'm not sure how to forward the client object parameters.

```
template<class client_connection, typename... client_parameters>
class tcp_server
{
private:
    tcp_server(const tcp_server&) = delete;
    tcp_server& operator=(const tcp_server&) = delete;

    boost::asio::io_service& io_service;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;

    void start_accept()
    {
        acceptor.async_accept(socket, [this](const boost::system::error_code& ec)
        {
            if (!ec)
            {
                std::make_shared<client_connection>(io_service, std::move(socket), client_params)->start();
            }

            start_accept();
        });
    }

public:
    tcp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, const std::string& address, const std::string& service, client_parameters&&...client_params)
        :
        io_service(io_service),
        acceptor(io_service),
        socket(io_service)
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(address, service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve(query);
        acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
        acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        acceptor.bind(endpoint);
        acceptor.listen();

        start_accept();
    }
};
```

Comment: `std::tuple<client_parameters&>` may help. Also `client_parameters&&...` are really rvalue references and not forwarding references.

Comment: @Jarod42 or `std::forward_as_tuple(client_parameters....)`?

Comment: *"The parameters shouldn't be copied, only referenced."* how do you guarantee they are alive when a client connects? can there be more clients that should receive the same parameters (not copied)?

Comment: The parameters are immutable, are singleton like ( created before the creation of the server, destroyed after the destruction of the server ) but the ammount of data is big, so I prefer not to copy them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do something like the following:

```
template<typename client_connection, typename... client_parameters>
class tcp_server
{
public:

    template <typename... Ts>
    explicit tcp_server(Ts&&... args) : client_params(std::forward<Ts>(args)...) {}

    std::unique_ptr<client_connection> CreateClient()
    {
        return CreateClient(std::index_sequence_for<client_parameters...>{});
    }

private:
    template <std::size_t...Is>
    std::unique_ptr<client_connection> CreateClient(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return std::make_unique<client_connection>(std::get<Is>(client_params)...);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<client_parameters...> client_params;
};
```

And then have something like:

```
using my_server_t = tcp_server<MyConnection, BigType&, int>;
```

where you specify in the type which parameter are kept by reference or by value.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to build a general tcp_server a template, and I want to forward some parameters to the client class after the connection is created. However, the client object creation happens only after he has connected, and not during the tcp_server construction. How do I pass the parameters from the tcp_server constructor to the client constructor ?

Make a copy or reference to the parameters in `tcp_server`. Then pass these parameters to `client_connection` constructor.

> The parameters shouldn't be copied, only referenced.

Use references or pointers then.

Comment: I want to use both tcp_server<client_connection_type1, param1, param2, param3> and tcp_server<client_connection_type2, param1, param2>. I want to build a more abstract template.